# My phpmyadmin page was in blank after installed

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

i am new to PHP, currently working in php. 
so for practice php i have installed xampp server on my laptop. 
After installed i opened phpmyadmin in browser, its not showing any error, the page was in blank. 
I have searched more i dint get answer for this problem. 
please any one help me.

Comment: Personally I always recommend people use Sequel Pro (Mac) or MySQL Workbench (win/linux/mac). Or if you need to connect to other DB's then Navicat Premium (but its not free like the other two). These applications are far better than a web based interface.

Comment: Actually i am running http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ in my browser. i am using mysql. my problem was phpmyadmin was not working. i dont know why its not coming.

Comment: @Vijaykarthik If you are using windows OS, I suggest you please choose wamp server for php,mysql,apache. Its easier to use.

Comment: blank page = something blew up. turn on display_errors and error_reporting in php.ini, restart everything, try again.

Comment: Thanks for your help sir, i got phpmyadmin in xampp server thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the apache error log? Usually at /var/log/apacher/error.log, I think there might be a logs button on xampp you can click and select Apache error log. Google says the xampp error log path is [xampp install folder]\apache\logs\error.log. Anyway, there is probably a PHP error in that log.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your localhost port is not set to 80 (the default), otherwise you need to manually adjust the port in the browser URL.